# TXMLNodeList NodeName #text

Tags: delphi

I trying to iterate through xml nodes and attributes with IXMLDocument (sort of Lua interpreter). ProcessNode procedure like

```
procedure ProcessNode(node: IXMLNode);
var
  cNode: IXMLNode;
  nList: IXMLNodeList;
  i: integer;
begin
  if node = nil then
    exit;
  PrintLocal(format('%s %s', [node.NodeName, GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TNodeType), Ord(node.NodeType))]));
  nList := node.AttributeNodes;
  for i := 0 to nList.Count - 1 do
    PrintLocal(format('%s %s %s', [nList[i].NodeName, node.Attributes[nList[i].NodeName], GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TNodeType), Ord(nList[i].NodeType))]));

  cNode := node.ChildNodes.First;
  while cNode <> nil do begin
    ProcessNode(cNode);
    cNode := cNode.NextSibling;
  end;
end;
```

When xml like
`<Content Items.Text="+\n-\n*\n/" ItemIndex="0" />`
I have proper node names and can get values

```
Items.Text +\n-\n*\n/ ntAttribute
ItemIndex 0 ntAttribute
```

but when xml like

```
<Items>
    <Text>+\n-\n*\n/</Text>
</Items>
<ItemIndex>0</ItemIndex>
```

I have

```
Items ntElement
Text ntElement
#text ntText
ItemIndex ntElement
#text ntText
```

How to retrieve values from such types of nodes when NodeName is "#text"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `Node.NodeType` for `ntText` and get value from `Node.Text`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can also use `INode.IsTextElement` property.